# cakephp saveall with dynamic number of elements in the form

Tags: php, cakephp

// add.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('City');?>
    <fieldset>

        <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('City.city_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('City.city_latitude');
        echo $this->Form->input('City.city_longitude');
        ?>
        <div class="add_more_city"><button class="btn green">Add More</button></div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'title' => 'Click here to add the city')); ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add_more_city').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).before('City Name<input name="data[City][city_name]" maxlength="100" type="text" id="CityCityName" required="required"/>City Latitude<input name="data[City][city_latitude]" step="any" type="number" id="CityCityLatitude" required="required"/></div><div class="input number required"><label for="CityCityLongitude">City Longitude</label><input name="data[City][city_longitude]" step="any" type="number" id="CityCityLongitude" required="required"/></div>');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

//City Controller

```
public function add() {
        if(!$this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login'));      
        }else{
            if(AuthComponent::user('role')=='Admin'){
                if ($this->request->is('post')) {    
                    $this->City->create();
                        if ($this->City->saveAll($this->request->data)) {

                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('City has been added '));
                            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'cities','action' => 'add'));
                        } else {
                            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The city has not added. Please, try again.'));
                        } 
                }
            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('You are not authorized to access it'));
                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'users','action' => 'login'));
            }
        }
    }
```

//Model

```
<?php
    App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
    class city extends AppModel {
         public $validate = array(
           'city_name' => array(
            'nonEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A city name is required',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            ),
            'between' => array(
                'rule' => array('between', 3, 100),
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'City must be between 3 to 100 characters'
            ),
            'valid' => array(
                'rule'    => "/[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[ '-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*/",
                'message' => 'City can only be letters, numbers, comma and hyphen'
            )
        ),

        'city_latitude' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A Latitude is required'
            ),
            'valid' => array(
                'rule'=> '/^[-+]?([1-8]?\d(\.\d+)?|90(\.0+)?)/',
                'message'=> 'Valid latitude is required'
            )

        ),
        'city_longitude' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A Longitude is required'
            ),
            'valid' => array(
                'rule'=> '/\s*[-+]?(180(\.0+)?|((1[0-7]\d)|([1-9]?\d))(\.\d+)?)$/',
                'message'=> 'Valid Longitude is required'
            )
        )

    );


        /**
     * Before isUniqueUsername
     * @param array $options
     * @return boolean
     */


    }

?>
```

I want to use the saveAll to save multiple city data together. Form to add text input to add multiple city is triggered with the help of add more button(java function). Cakephp saveAll is not working. could you help me to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my solution. The problem was with the field. I am dynamically updating the name parameter of the form.

```
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('City');?>
        <fieldset>
        <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('city_name', array('name' => 'City[0][city_name]'));
echo $this->Form->input('city_latitude', array('name' => 'City[0][city_latitude]'));
echo $this->Form->input('city_longitude', array('name' => 'City[0][city_longitude]'));
        ?>
        <div class="extra"></div>
        <div class="add_more_city" id="add_more_1"><button class="btn green">Add More</button></div>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Save', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'title' => 'Click here to add the city')); ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>





<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add_more_city').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var get_id=$('.add_more_city').attr('id');
            var split_id=get_id.split('_');
            var id = parseInt(split_id[2]);
            var id_update =id+1;
            $('.add_more_city').attr('id','add_more_'+id_update);
            $('.extra').before(' <div class="input text"><label for="CityCityName">City Name</label><input name="City['+id+'][city_name]" maxlength="100" type="text" id="CityCityName"/></div><div class="input number"><label for="CityCityLatitude">City Latitude</label><input name="City['+id+'][city_latitude]" step="any" type="number" id="CityCityLatitude"/></div><div class="input number"><label for="CityCityLongitude">City Longitude</label><input name="City['+id+'][city_longitude]" step="any" type="number" id="CityCityLongitude"/></div></div>');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I was guessing the issue would be the field names. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the field names -

```
echo $this->Form->input('city_name', array('name' => 'City[][city_name]'));
echo $this->Form->input('city_latitude', array('name' => 'City[][city_latitude]'));
echo $this->Form->input('city_longitude', array('name' => 'City[][city_longitude]'));
```

Comment: the field generated by this is <div class="input text"><label for="City[]CityName">City Name</label><input name="data[City][[]][city_name]" maxlength="100" type="text" id="City[]CityName"/></div><div class="input number"><label for="City[]CityLatitude">City Latitude</label><input name="data[City][[]][city_latitude]" step="any" type="number" id="City[]CityLatitude"/></div><div class="input number"><label for="City[]CityLongitude">City Longitude</label><input name="data[City][[]][city_longitude]" step="any" type="number" id="City[]CityLongitude"/></div>

Comment: and var_dump gives me array(1) { ["City"]=> array(1) { ["["]=> string(1) "1" } }

Comment: Updated the answer. Give it a try,

Comment: @ sgt BOSE its not working and the field generated by this is <div class="input text"><label for="City[][cityName]">[city Name]</label><input name="data[City][[]][[city_name]]" type="text" id="City[][cityName]"/></div><div class="input text"><label for="City[][cityLatitude]">[city Latitude]</label><input name="data[City][[]][[city_latitude]]" type="text" id="City[][cityLatitude]"/></div><div class="input text"><label for="City[][cityLongitude]">[city Longitude]</label><input name="data[City][[]][[city_longitude]]" type="text" id="City[][cityLongitude]"/></div>

Comment: It is not generating the field name as needed. Pass them as options. Updated the code.

Comment: its not working var_dump gives me array(1) { ["City"]=> array(6) { [0]=> array(1) { ["city_name"]=> string(5) "sdm s" } [1]=> array(1) { ["city_latitude"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(1) { ["city_longitude"]=> string(1) "1" } [3]=> array(1) { ["city_name"]=> string(4) "asdj" } [4]=> array(1) { ["city_latitude"]=> string(1) "1" } [5]=> array(1) { ["city_longitude"]=> string(1) "1" } } }
and the field generated is this <div class="input text"><label for="CityCityName">City Name</label><input name="City[][city_name]" maxlength="100" type="text" id="CityCityName"/></div>

Comment: it is not saving now?

Comment: Check if the `beforeSave` is getting called.

Comment: There is no any validation in the model. I have removed all the validators. Still its not saving in the database

Comment: Check if the beforeSave is getting called.

Comment: yeah its getting called

Comment: debug it for `$this->data`. if the data is coming properly then it will save them.

Comment: Debugger::dump($this->data), Just before $this->City->saveAll gives, array(
 'City' => array(
  (int) 0 => array(
   'city_name' => 'sddsjdfjfd'
  ),
  (int) 1 => array(
   'city_latitude' => '12'
  ),
  (int) 2 => array(
   'city_longitude' => '2'
  ),
  (int) 3 => array(
   'city_name' => 'sdfsdnfn'
  ),
  (int) 4 => array(
   'city_latitude' => '12'
  ),
  (int) 5 => array(
   'city_longitude' => '1'
  )
 )
) but its not saving in the database @sgt BOSE